# Customize Django admin site for User

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to hide the is_staff and is_superuser fields in the Django admin site. I've put this in a local admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = ( 
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )   
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    list_filter = ('is_active', 'groups')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

It's not working though. The fields are still in the admin site.

Here's my installed apps. I have my admin.py in the materials app.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.admindocs',
  'home',
  'materials',
  'south',
  'functional_tests',
  'reports',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin.py needs to be within an actual django app, i.e. something that's in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. The code you've posted should work fine.

Edit: for future reference the issue was another app altering the user admin.

Comment: It's in an installed app.

Comment: Is it actually being imported? Try adding `print "hello"` at the end of the file, and see if "hello" pops up in your console.

Comment: Yes, "hello" does appear in my console.

Comment: Can you post your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? Does your app come after `'django.contrib.auth'`?

Comment: Just posted them. I have admin.py in the materials app. It does come after django.contrib.auth.

Comment: Any other apps altering the user admin?

Answer (score 0):

Please be explanatory if you want to remove those fields from list_display or edit form and you can try

exclude = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')

This should do the trick.